# How to configure GitVersion for Release Flow?

Tags: git, branching-strategy, gitversion

I am trying to configure GitVersion to work with the [Release Flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/19/release-flow-how-we-do-branching-on-the-vsts-team/) branching strategy.

[image]

Basically, I have a mainline Master branch, Release, Feature and Fix branches. The Feature and Fix branches are created from the Master branch and merged back into Master via a pull request. At the end of a sprint, I create a Release branch from Master, which will last till the end of the next sprint, when a new Release branch will be created. The Release branches are not merged back into master. They can even be deleted after a new Release branch has been created. If there's a hotfix needed, it will be developed on a Fix branch created from and merged back into master and then cherry-picked into the current Release branch. I only use git tags for major releases.

Going back to GitVersion, I want to configure it so that the minor version number will increase when I create a new release branch and the patch number to increase when there's a new commit on the release branch (cherry-picked from a Fix branch).

Has anyone done that already and can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use flow pretty similar to this one (actually based on it). 
We do hotfixes right on release branches and we also create pre-release branches before release ones (convenient to have separate channels in octopus-deploy).

After a [bit struggle](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/created_by/AnSmol), i ended up with my own [PowerShell script](https://github.com/AnSmol/HandyPoshScripts/blob/master/DevOps/SemVerCalc_PreReleaseFlow.ps1).
The script is simple and works super fast (near 1 second, unlike GitVersion, which could work 5-15 minutes on our huge repos with big amount of branches). 
Now, the result looks like that:

[image]

It mostly designed to usage with TeamCity, but i think you could easily change it to feet you needs.
You can see detailed description of calculation algorithm inside script comments.
It also briefly explained on this diagram:

[image]

Caveat:
In future/topic branches, unlike GitVersion, script uses always growing build counter from teamcity, instead of commits counter. I had to do it, when i found out than our colleges use force pushes(some "clean history" politics), and i can't rely on commits history.

Comment: BTW, i there is also a [script](https://github.com/AnSmol/HandyPoshScripts/blob/master/DevOps/AssemblyInfoPatcher.ps1)  that mimics GitVersion assemblyInfo patching functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it might work. I am going to wait a couple of weeks to see if anyone else answers. If not I'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: @AntonSmolkov Thank you for this! This will be of much help as we are looking to follow the ReleaseFlow principal in our team for new stuff we build. I'd also be interested in how you've set things up on Octopus as well as on TeamCity. Like, do you guys automatically push every feature branch into dev or what's your story? Also, would be awesome to see how you've setup Octopus as we are using OctpusDeploy ourselves so any pointers are of interest.

Comment: @mengstorm You welcome! No, we use pull-requests to merge code from feature-brances to master. Our pipeline looks wery close to described [here](https://octopususergroup.slack.com/archives/CBS54TR9S/p1550696163026600)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work doing an Anti-Pattern for just one part of release flow. But this is not a big deal if you use Azure DevOps because Microsoft provides a quick and easy way to see if your release branch is ahead/behind the master branch. I have tested this and I am using Release Flow for almost complete automation of versioning besides creating a release branch, and new tag at the end of each sprint. This method also is working well for Semantic Versioning 2.0 of my Nuget Packages, which I use views instead of the suffix tags.

[Modified Release Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dwab.png)

I apologize, and hope it is not too late to help someone out. I have added the yml, and I also have a powershell that I made to handle the release branch naming when cherry picking a HF from master. Note that this powershell step adds a version tag on a release branch so that GitVersion will pick it up.

Powershell: 
Release {{TeamProject}}/{{RepoName}} with your team project and repo name

```
- powershell: |
   $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=2.0" 
   Write-Host "URL:" $url 
   $definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } 
   Write-Host "Pipeline = $($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
  displayName: Build Details
  env: 
   SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)

- powershell: |
   #Get branch version and increment from release branch
   $branchName = "$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"
   $versionNotIncremented = ($branchName -Split "-")[1]
   [System.Version] $version = "0.0"
   [System.Version]::TryParse($versionNotIncremented, [ref]$version) > Null
   $ver = New-Object System.Version($version.Major,($version.Minor + 1))
   #Create new commit and tag on master
   git checkout master
   $env:GIT_TRACE=1
   git pull
   git commit --allow-empty -m "Create Tag ***NO_CI***"
   git push https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/{{TeamProject}}/{{RepoName}}/_git/{{TeamProject}}.Lookup.Api
   $commitId = git log --format="%h" -n 1
   #$commitId = git rev-parse --short HEAD
   git tag $ver $commitId -f -m "Release-$ver"
   git push https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/{{TeamProject}}/{{RepoName}}/_git/{{TeamProject}}.Lookup.Api $ver -f --porcelain
  displayName: 'Update Version for Upcoming Release'
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/'))
  env: 
   SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

GitVersion Yaml:

```
assembly-informational-format: '{FullSemVer}'
mode: Mainline
branches:
  master:
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: master|releases?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: features?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: (pull|pull\-requests|pr|[0-9]+)[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: hotfix(es)?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: unstable
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
ignore:
  sha: []
```

Comment: Let me know if you need to see the GitVersion YML file

Comment: Yes, sure. Please add it in the answer so I can see it.

Comment: @Stoopered I'm interested in the yml file too, please add it to the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @stoopered could you plz add the gitversion config yml file, I m running into the same issue with gitversion,